# Bash case menu wont call to function: Command not found

Tags: bash

I have tried to create a bash script which has a case menu, that calls a function when chosen:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Menu
PS3='Vælg en funktion: '
options=("1: fileSplitter" "2: rowGrepper" "3: grepCounter?" "4: exit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "1: fileSplitter") fileSplitter ;;
        "2: rowGrepper") rowGrepper ;;
        "3: grepCounter?") grepCounter ;;
        "4: exit") break ;;
        *) echo "$REPLY er ikke tilgængeligt.." ;;
    esac
done

# Functions
function fileSplitter() {
        echo "fileSplitter function"
}

function rowGrepper() {
        echo "rowGrepper function"
}

function grepCounter() {
        echo "grepCounter"
}
```

But when choosing option one, two or three that calls the specified functions, i get the error: **fileSplitter: command not found**

Comment: You need to define a function before you can call it, so the `#Functions`-section should be at the beginning of the script.

Comment: `bash` (probably any shell) is evaluated line by line (or rather command by command). It's not a programming language that is parsed before execution.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you, the problem was caused by the order of menu and functions.
It works perfectly when stating the functons before the menu:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Functions:
function fileSplitter() {
        echo "fileSplitter function"
}

function rowGrepper() {
        echo "rowGrepper function"
}

function grepCounter() {
        echo "grepCounter"
}

# Menu:
PS3='Vælg en funktion: '
options=("1: fileSplitter" "2: rowGrepper" "3: grepCounter?" "4: exit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "1: fileSplitter") fileSplitter ;;
        "2: rowGrepper") rowGrepper ;;
        "3: grepCounter?") grepCounter ;;
        "4: exit") break ;;
        *) echo "$REPLY er ikke tilgængeligt.." ;;
    esac
done
```

Result:

```
./csv_helper.sh 
1) 1: fileSplitter
2) 2: rowGrepper
3) 3: grepCounter?
4) 4: exit
Vælg en funktion: 1
fileSplitter function
```